# Inserting a jpeg image at a specified point in the XY-plane

Tags: graphics

I know how to import an image into Mathematica using the `Import` command.  The original image can come from anywhere, but call this image "myimage" after importing into Mathematica

Now my problem is how to insert this image at the point with coordinates (2,3) in the XY-plane.  I know how to insert certain text at a prescribed place, but with imported images, I am not sure how to do it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!  Please consider registering your account.  It'll open up the way to using many features of this site, such as editing your question at any later time and commenting on answers for clarifications.

Answer (score 11):

In `Graphics` expressions, you can use [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html) in a very similar way to `Text`:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDnKs.png"]

Graphics[Inset[img, {2, 3}], Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The third argument of `Inset` will control which point in it will be positioned at the given coordinates.

For more precise control, you can use [`Raster`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Raster.html):

```
Graphics[
 Raster[ImageData[img, DataReversed -> True], {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}], 
 Frame -> True]
```

`Raster` is just like `Rectangle`, but it renders an image inside.  Don't forget to use `DataReversed -> True` in `ImageData` to get the image data in a format compatible with `Raster`.

Comment: Thnak you very much to all of you!  I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 7):

You need `Inset`:

```
im = Image@Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 0.1]}];
Plot[x, {x, 0, 20}, Epilog -> Inset[im, {15, 15}]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Adjust size of inserted image: `Inset[Show[im, ImageSize -> 50], {15, 15}]`